# How does this work in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Ok so i dont understand regex checker works in ruby

```
=~

1.9.2p290 :009 > url = "/myurl"
 => "/myurl" 
1.9.2p290 :010 > url =~ %r{^/.*/found/\d+$}i
 => nil 
1.9.2p290 :011 > url = "/myurl/found/1"
 => "/myurl/found/1" 
1.9.2p290 :012 > url =~ %r{^/.*/found/\d+$}i
 => 0
```

It seems to return a value of something if found otherwise it returns nil ...but i dont know for sure
....where is the documentation for this anywhere...i tried to google for this and no luck at all...any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check out http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E and http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-3D-7E for some documentation on the =~ method(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it matches, it returns the position of the beginning of the match. Otherwise, returns nil. The `0` in your last example means that the substring that matched the regex starts from position `0` of the original string.

Comment: I have no idea how to access this url[0]
 => "/"  and where is the documentation if you know

Comment: @Tamer What is `url`? You should not use variables without explaining. It is a very basic stuff. Perhaps you can look for the Regexp class in ruby-doc.org for documentation.

Comment: I have it in my question "/myurl/found/1"

Comment: I realize what you mean the 0 character is where the regex starts the match but i was wondering if there was documentation about this somewhere

Comment: I see. Sorry. if `url` is `"/myurl"`, then the character at position 0 is its first character "/".